# Validating Integer Input

Tags: c, variables

```
int a;
scanf("%d",&a);
```

How can I ensure the code doesn't work if a non-digit character is given as input to the `scanf()` statement? [I need a solution that doesn't make me change the data type to `char`]

Comment: By reading the documentation for scanf and making use of the return value. Simple!

Comment: Thanks! The return value did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first character is not a digit, then `%d` will fail to match, and `a` will not be assigned. The return value of `scanf` tells you how many items were assigned. If it's one, then clearly it was at least partially a valid number. If it's zero, that means it couldn't be parsed as a number, and you may want to signal an error.

Comment: Thanks! Finally understood this.

Answer (score 2):

The `scanf` return code will tell you how many items in your arg list were filled. This may still not be what you want: I think you'll find input "123four" will still return 1, with a=123.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a do while loop for validating input from user
like:

```
int read,a;
do {
        read = scanf("%c", &a);
    }while(read != EOF && a != '\n'); //change validation here according to condition
```